# How to find all the $z$ that satisfy $(1+i)z^4=(1-i)|z|^2$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Would you please help me solve this? I need all the $z$ that satisfy the equality

$$(1+i)z^4=(1-i)|z|^2.$$

I tried doing this:

$$
\begin{aligned}
(1+i)z^4&= (1-i)z\overline z\\
(1+i)z^4 -(1-i)z\overline z &= 0\\
z[(1+i)z^3-(1-i)\overline z]&= 0
\end{aligned}
$$

Then $z= 0$ and 
$$(1+i)z^3-(1-i)\overline z= 0.$$

I don't know what to do with $\overline z$.

Comment: Consider the absolute value of both sides, then you can easily see that $z$ must be uni-modular or zero. That is $|z|=0, 1.$ Than take $z=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ and substitute to your equation to find particular conditions on $\theta.$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

$$(1+i)z^4=(1-i)|z|^2\iff z^4=\dfrac{1-i}{1+i}|z|^2=-i|z|^2.$$

Taking modulus we have $|z|=0$ or $|z|=1.$ In the first case it is $z=0.$ In the second case $z=e^{i\theta}.$ So, we have

$$\cos (4\theta)+i\sin(4\theta)=-i.$$ That is, we have to solve

\begin{cases}\cos(4\theta)=0\\\sin(4\theta)=-1\end{cases}

Comment: I dont understand why you consider the modulus as 0 and 1

Comment: $z^4=-i|z|^2\implies |z|^4=|z^4|=|-i|z|^2|=|-i||z|^2=|z|^2\implies  |z|^4=|z|^2.$

Comment: There is an easier way to solve $e^{4i\theta}=-i$. Just use $e^{4i\theta}=e^{3\pi i/2+2k\pi i}$, or $4i\theta=3\pi/2 i+2k\pi i$.

Answer (score 0):

$$(1+i)z^4=(1-i)|z|^2\iff iz^4=z\bar z\iff\begin{cases}z=0\\iz^3=\bar z\end{cases}$$ $$iz^3=\bar z\iff i(a+ib)^3=(a-ib)\iff {ia^3 - 3 a^2 b -i 3 a b^2 + b^3}=(a-ib)\\\iff   b^3- 3 a^2 b  +i(a^3 - 3 a b^2)=a-ib\iff\begin{cases}b^3- 3 a^2 b=a\\a^3 - 3 a b^2=-b\end{cases}$$

We can also notice that $|b^3- 3 a^2 b  +i(a^3 - 3 a b^2)|=\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)^3}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=|a-ib|\implies
|z|=\begin{cases}1\\0\end{cases}$, so it comes with terms with @mfl's answer

Comment: No idea why you send the OP to the real part / imaginary part decomposition when it only complicates things. How would you solve $iz^9=\bar z$, one wonders...